# How to update the progressbar value in particular intervals?

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to show the upload progress details in Html progress bar. It working fine. But i would like to update the details on every "30%" completed.
So the progressbar should be updated for **30%, 60%, 90% and completed**

My code .

```
  <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" onchange="uploadFile()"><br>

  <progress id="progressBar" class='progressbar' value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;height:5px"></progress>



var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);

function progressHandler(event) {
  var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
  document.getElementById("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent) ;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just round up the percent to closest 30:

```
function progressHandler(event) {
  var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
  var done = Math.round(percent/30) * 30;
  document.getElementById("progressBar").value = Math.round(done) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to separate the cases using an `if...else` construct. I've edited the code to use `setInterval` to simulate a file upload.

```html
<progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;height:15px"></progress>

<script>

var evt=0,progShow;
upd=setInterval(progressHandler,50);

function progressHandler() {
  evt++;
  if (evt>=100) {clearInterval(upd);progShow=100;}
  if (evt<30) progShow=0;
  else if (evt>29 && evt<60) progShow=30;
  else if (evt>59 && evt<90) progShow=60;
  else if (evt>89 && evt<100) progShow=90;
  document.getElementById("progressBar").value = progShow;
 }
 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reinventing the wheel, consider using one of the many existing upload components available. Fit.UI has a really neat one - the demo has both file previews and progress indicators: http://fitui.org/Control-FilePicker.html

[image]

Here is a fork of the demo that increments the progress the way you want:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/k18uy2o0/